# Symfony Error: Class contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I created a CustomAuthenticator.
When I access the login page, I get the following error:

> Error: Class App\Repository\UserRepository contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface::loadUserByUsername)

My UserRepository code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use function get_class;

/**
 * @extends ServiceEntityRepository<User>
 *
 * @method User|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method User|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method User[]    findAll()
 * @method User[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    public function add(User $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    public function remove(User $entity, bool $flush = false): void
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($entity);

        if ($flush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function upgradePassword(PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface $user, string $newHashedPassword): void
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
        }

        $user->setPassword($newHashedPassword);

        $this->add($user, true);
    }

    public function findAllUsers($ownUser, $q = null)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('user');
        $query = $qb
            ->select('u')
            ->from('App\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->where('u.firstname LIKE :user')
            ->orWhere('u.lastname LIKE :user')
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->neq('u.id', $ownUser))
            ->setParameter('user',  $q)
            ->setParameter('user', '%'. $q . '%')
            ->orderBy('u.firstname', 'ASC')
            ->distinct()
            ->getQuery();
        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }

    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $usernameOrEmail): ?User
    {

        if (!filter_var($usernameOrEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $name = explode(" ", $usernameOrEmail, -1);
            dump($name);
            exit();
        }

        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.email = :emailOrUsername')
            ->orWhere('u.username = :emailOrUsername')
            ->setParameter('emailOrUsername', $usernameOrEmail)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }

//    /**
//     * @return User[] Returns an array of User objects
//     */
//    public function findByExampleField($value): array
//    {
//        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
//            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
//            ->setParameter('val', $value)
//            ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC')
//            ->setMaxResults(10)
//            ->getQuery()
//            ->getResult()
//        ;
//    }

//    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?User
//    {
//        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
//            ->andWhere('u.exampleField = :val')
//            ->setParameter('val', $value)
//            ->getQuery()
//            ->getOneOrNullResult()
//        ;
//    }
}
```

How can I fix that error?

Comment: Did you **read** the error message? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

> ### PHP - Using Interfaces
>
> To implement an interface, a class must use the
> `implements` keyword.
>
> A class that implements an interface must implement **all** of the
> interface's methods.
>
> -- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_interfaces.asp

Your repository implements [`Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/UserLoaderInterface.php) which has exactly one method `loadUserByUsername` that you must define yourself in your repository class.
Refer to the comments in the source code below for guidance:

```php
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Represents a class that loads UserInterface objects from Doctrine source for the authentication system.
 *
 * This interface is meant to facilitate the loading of a User from Doctrine source using a custom method.
 * If you want to implement your own logic of retrieving the user from Doctrine your repository should implement this
 * interface.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 *
 * @method UserInterface|null loadUserByIdentifier(string $identifier) loads the user for the given user identifier (e.g. username or email).
 *                                                                     This method must return null if the user is not found.
 *
 * @author Michal Trojanowski <michal@kmt-studio.pl>
 */
interface UserLoaderInterface
{
    /**
     * @return UserInterface|null
     *
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use loadUserByIdentifier() instead
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername(string $username);
}
```

So you should be able to just add the following method:

```php
public function loadUserByUsername(string $username)
{
  return $this->loadUserByIdentifier($username);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. loadUserByUsername Is outdated according to the comment. Or have I misunderstood? For this reason I used loadUserByIdentifier. See comment: @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use loadUserByIdentifier () instead

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that part. That's still the only method so it must be defined. You have done the correct thing by using `loadUserByIdentifier` but now you need `loadUserByUsername` and you can just have it call `loadUserByIdentifier` that way you stay forward compatible. The way I understand it, If you never plan on updating beyond Symfony5 then you do not need to worry about having `loadUserByIdentifier`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So how do I have to change my code? Sorry for the stupid questions.

Comment: Just for info, Symfony 5 basically changed from username to identifier.  Some of the interfaces are basically in transition.  In Symfony 6 the interface has been changed to loadUserByIdentifier.  So as the answer suggests, keep your loadUserByIdentifier method intact and just call it from loadUserByUsername.  When you move to Symfony 6 things will continue to work though, at that time, you could remove the loadUserByUsername.

Comment: @Cerad

The problem has now been solved. The error doesn’t appear anymore.

Now I only have the problem that this method is not called when logging in. Do I have to say explicitly that this method should be used when logging in?

Comment: @Luu You do have to specify that the class/service should be used as the user provider.  This is typically done in config/packages/services.yaml.  Usually with app_user_provider.  Check the docs for details.